# Formulating a bottom-up dynamic programming premise for a board game

Tags: dynamic-programming

The game being played here has the following rules, played be a singular player: there is a 5x5 board, where some tiles are highlighted and some are not. From here, the player can highlight the blank tiles, but they can't reverted a highlighted tile to blank. when a tile is highlighted, the player gets a score for that move, which is calculated as follows:

The base score for any move is 1. now say I've highlighted (1,3) and the tiles (1,1), (1,2), (1,4) and (1,5) were all highlighted. there are 4 tiles horizontally adjacent to the one on which I moved, so the score of the move is increased by 4, to now be 5 total.

Say the tiles (2,3), and (3,3) are also highlighted, being vertically adjacent. we can add 2 more to that score.

If, and only if, both a column and a row are found adjacently highlighted, a bonus point will be added. so if (2,3) wasn't highlighted, our score for the move would be 5, but since it was, it become 5+2+1=8. as the game goes on, the scores of each move add up. the goal obviously being to get the maximum possible score.

so I've been attempting to formulate a bottom-up dynamic programming premise for this, but I'm unsure of how.

I've concluded that the base case is simply a full board, from which we progressively un-highlight tiles until we reach the starting position the board would've had if we played regularly.

The first move undone from a full board will always yield the same score.

since all tiles are highlighted, it would be (width + length + 1) depending on board dimensions.

from here I'm unsure of how to approach the rest in a solely iterative manner. The corresponding table, I would assume would contain possible scores, where each column represents the coordinate of an empty tile, and each row represents how many moves have been made so far, so the 4th row would have the subproblem "which combinations of 4 empty tiles allow the highest score for this move?"

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info